# transform.position not working in Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm really new to Unity 3d and I'm trying to make a respawn with my character. It seems that the answer is really easy but I cannot see why my code is not working. If this is a duplicate, let me know.

```cs
public Vector3 PointSpawn;

void Start()
{
    PointSpawn = gameObject.transform.position;
}

void Update()
{
    if (gameObject.transform.position.y < 10)
    {
       gameObject.transform.position = PointSpawn;   // This doesn't work

       // gameObject.transform.LookAt(PointSpawn);   ---> This DOES work ok
    }
}
```

**Parallel Script**

```cs
public float HorizontalMove;
public float VerticalMove;
private Vector3 playerInput;

public CharacterController player;

public float MoveSpeed;
private Vector3 movePlayer;
public float gravity = 9.8f;
public float fallVelocity;
public float JumpForce;
public bool DoubleJump = false;

public Camera mainCamera;
private Vector3 camForward;
private Vector3 camRight;

void Start()
{
    player = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update()
{
    HorizontalMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    VerticalMove = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    playerInput = new Vector3(HorizontalMove, 0, VerticalMove);
    playerInput = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(playerInput, 1);

    CamDirection();

    movePlayer = playerInput.x * camRight + playerInput.z * camForward;

    movePlayer = movePlayer * MoveSpeed;

    player.transform.LookAt(player.transform.position + movePlayer);

    setGravity();

    PlayerSkills();

    player.Move(movePlayer * Time.deltaTime );
}

void CamDirection()
{
    camForward = mainCamera.transform.forward;
    camRight = mainCamera.transform.right;

    camForward.y = 0;
    camRight.y = 0;

    camForward = camForward.normalized;
    camRight = camRight.normalized;
}

void PlayerSkills()
{
    if (player.isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        fallVelocity = JumpForce;
        movePlayer.y = fallVelocity;
        DoubleJump = true;
    }
    else if (player.isGrounded == false && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && DoubleJump == true)
    {
        fallVelocity = JumpForce *2;
        movePlayer.y = fallVelocity;
        DoubleJump = false;
    }
}
    
void setGravity()
{
    if (player.isGrounded)
    {
        fallVelocity = -gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        movePlayer.y = fallVelocity;
    }
    else
    {
        fallVelocity -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        movePlayer.y = fallVelocity;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the `LookAt` seems to work it is not your if conditional that is not getting broken into. Are you altering this `gameObject`'s position anywhere else? Or are you updating the `PointSpawn` anywhere else? If the `LookAt` works, then I would assume your position is getting set elsewhere in code that you have not provided. What does your movement code look like? Is it updating by position? Does it track its own previous position?

Comment: I am able to move the object with arrow keys, and I have a gravity code running in a parallel script every frame, maybe that is the problem(?. The `PointSpawn` is only assigned at the setup. I will add the parallel script to the question.

Comment: I believe that's the issue. Just put the check for the y position in `LateUpdate`. That way, all your other movement occurs first, then the respawn can happen after it. It also means the movement code should not overwrite the respawn. To clarify, your first snippet, just change `Update` to `LateUpdate`.

Comment: Glad I could help out. Posted the comment as an answer as SO does not like answers to be placed in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just so the answer to the question is not in the comments:

The original problem is that the assignment `gameObject.transform.position = PointSpawn` appeared to do nothing. As the line is written properly, the position of this `gameObject`, must have been getting overwritten elsewhere.

With the addition of OP's movement script, the position of the player was getting overwritten in the movement's `Update` function. As the other assignment was being done in `Update`, the call order was not guaranteed to work as intended. The fix is either to assure that the movement `Update` is run not the frame of the new position assignment or to move the conditional and the assignment to a function that always runs after `Update` regardless of script execution order, [`LateUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html).